# Use shutil.make_archive with zipfile.ZIP_STORED?

Tags: python, compression, zip, shutil

In Python is there a way to use the `shutil.make_archive()` function with file compression set to `zipfile.ZIP_STORED`? (that is, uncompressed)

The document shows that there are many optional parameters, but none of them sets the file compression:

```
shutil.make_archive(base_name, format[, root_dir[, base_dir[, verbose[, dry_run[, owner[, group[, logger]]]]]]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this with `shutil.make_archive`.

If the lack of a relevant flag in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive) isn't sufficient evidence, you can look at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/shutil.py#l740).

In particular, at [line 683](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/shutil.py#l683) you can see that it explicitly passes `compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED` if your Python has the `zipfile` module, while the fallback code at [line 634](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/shutil.py#l634) doesn't pass any arguments besides `-r` and `-q` to the `zip` command-line tool.

This is meant to be a high-level function that makes trivial cases easier; if you want to do anything `zip`/`tar`/`gztar`/`bztar`-specific, you can, and should, use the underlying libraries.

Of course if you need this frequently, you can write your own `make_archive`-like wrapper (just copy the relevant code out of `shutil` and modify your copy).

Comment: @twasbrillig: Thanks for the update edits! It looks like either a few line numbers have changed between 3.3 and 3.4, or I got them wrong in the first place, so I've had to move two of them around a couple lines.